# What can I do in JavaScript to make each drop down menu only appear after selecting the one before it?

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu

```html
            <div class="row">            
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <label for="selectCustomers">Customer Select</label>
                        <select class="form-control pointer" name="tableCustomers" id="tableCustomers" style="font-size:100%" >
                            <option id="nothing" value="">---Select---</option>
                            <option  id="1" value="1" >1</option>
                            <option  id="2" value="2">2</option>
                            <option  id="3" value="3">3</option>
                            <option  id="4" value="4">4</option>
                        </select>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <label for="selectBuilding">Chosen Customer, Building Select</label>
                        <select class="form-control pointer" name="tableCustomers" id="tableCustomers" style="font-size:100%">
                            <option id="nothing" value="">---Select---</option>
                            <option  id="5" value="5" >5</option>
                            <option  id="6" value="6">6</option>
                            <option  id="7" value="7">7</option>
                            <option  id="8" value="8">8</option>
                        </select>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <label for="selectBattery">Chosen Building, Battery Select</label>
                        <select class="form-control pointer" name="tableCustomers" id="tableCustomers" style="font-size:100%">
                            <option id="nothing" value="">---Select---</option>
                            <option  id="9" value="9" >9</option>
                            <option  id="10" value="10">10</option>
                            <option  id="11" value="11">11</option>
                            <option  id="12" value="12">12</option>
                        </select>
                </div>
            </div>
```

I want it to only show the first dropdown menu (selectCustomers) when you first load onto
the page. After selecting an option other than id="nothing" it will show the next dropdown.

Comment: Add event listeners to the dropdowns that update your document. There's lots of ways to hide/disable dropdowns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add all your selects in array, and add `change` event listener for each to remove `hide` class from the next `select`

```js
const firstSelect = document.getElementById('tableCustomers1');
const secondSelect = document.getElementById('tableCustomers2');
const thirdSelect = document.getElementById('tableCustomers3');



const selectArray = [firstSelect, secondSelect, thirdSelect]
selectArray.forEach((select, i) => select.addEventListener('change', () => {
  const nextSelect = selectArray[i + 1]
  if (nextSelect) {
    nextSelect.closest('.hide').classList.remove('hide');
  }
}))
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">            
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <label for="selectCustomers">Customer Select</label>
                        <select class="form-control pointer" name="tableCustomers" id="tableCustomers1" style="font-size:100%" >
                            <option id="nothing" value="">---Select---</option>
                            <option  id="1" value="1" >1</option>
                            <option  id="2" value="2">2</option>
                            <option  id="3" value="3">3</option>
                            <option  id="4" value="4">4</option>
                        </select>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 hide">
                    <label for="selectBuilding">Chosen Customer, Building Select</label>
                        <select class="form-control pointer" name="tableCustomers" id="tableCustomers2" style="font-size:100%">
                            <option id="nothing" value="">---Select---</option>
                            <option  id="5" value="5" >5</option>
                            <option  id="6" value="6">6</option>
                            <option  id="7" value="7">7</option>
                            <option  id="8" value="8">8</option>
                        </select>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 hide">
                    <label for="selectBattery">Chosen Building, Battery Select</label>
                        <select class="form-control pointer" name="tableCustomers" id="tableCustomers3" style="font-size:100%">
                            <option id="nothing" value="">---Select---</option>
                            <option  id="9" value="9" >9</option>
                            <option  id="10" value="10">10</option>
                            <option  id="11" value="11">11</option>
                            <option  id="12" value="12">12</option>
                        </select>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Thank you, where does the .hide {
  display: none;
}
go

Comment: You are welcome, it is just a `CSS` class to hide the `select` you can use it or replace it with any class that can do the same.